# What's wrong with using pointer in a struct when passing it to gets()?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, gets

I have the following code. In the struct definition, I try to ask user to enter employee's first and last name. But when I run this exe, it exit after the title is entered. Any suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define NUMEMPS 10

struct Employee {
char *firstname;
char *lastname;
char *title;
int  salary;
};

int main()
{ 
 struct Employee* stuff = malloc(NUMEMPS* sizeof *stuff);
 int n,i;
 for (n=0; n<NUMEMPS;n++)
 {
  printf("Please enter number %d Employee's Last name:", n);
  fflush(stdout);
  gets(stuff[n].lastname);
  if (strlen(stuff[n].lastname) == 0)
  break;
  printf("Please enter number %d Employee's first name:", n);
  fflush(stdout);
  gets(stuff[n].firstname);
  printf("Please enter number %d Employee's title:", n);
  fflush(stdout);
  gets(stuff[n].title);
  printf("Please enter number %d Employee's salary:", n);
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &stuff[n].salary);
  getchar();
  }
  for (i = 0;i<n;i++)
  {
  printf("{%s,%s,%s,%d}\n", 
         stuff[i].lastname,
         stuff[i].firstname,
         stuff[i].title,
         stuff[i].salary);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Do not use `gets()`; it is no longer a part of Standard C and is never safe to use, regardless of any other problems.  Use `fgets()` or `getline()` instead, remembering that both of these include the delimiter (newline) in the result string whereas `gets()` leaves it out.  And do check the result from every input operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html](`getline`) is defined by POSIX, but not by the C standard. It might not exist on all systems -- or there might be a different function of the same name.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes; that's why I put `fgets()` first, though I admit I did not include the URLs as I normally do, nor did I explicitly call out `getline()` as POSIX-only.

Comment: regarding this line: struct Employee* stuff = malloc(NUMEMPS* sizeof *stuff);   this only allocates room for 10 pointers, not 10 'struct Employee'  There are some other problems in the code, like putting the employee array on the stack, but this is the first/main problem.

Comment: The reading of the strings has no place to contain the strings.  I.E. each and every string pointer in each and every employee struct needs either a malloc to pre-allocate some memory to hold the string or the struct fields need to be modified to define a (large enough for longest entry) array of characters.  naturally if the malloc method is used, then all those memory allocations will need to be free'd.

Comment: regarding this line: struct Employee* stuff = malloc(NUMEMPS* sizeof *stuff);  aside from the above comment, that malloc'd area is never free'd, so the code already has a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

The three `char*` members of the structure are *pointers*, so no space is allocated to hold any data.

With the current `struct` you'd have to do three more allocs for the data:

```
struct Employee* stuff = malloc(NUMEMPS* sizeof *stuff);
stuff->firstname = malloc(101);
stuff->lastname = malloc(101);
stuff->title = malloc(101);
```

What you probably want is something like:

```
struct Employee {
    char firstname[101];
    char lastname[101];
    char title[101];
    int  salary;
    };
```

Also, though as an aside, you must check your `malloc` calls for a NULL return.

Comment: Note that he sizes are whatever you want or deem appropriate. I just picked `101` out of the air (allowing for 100 bytes of data and a null terminator).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
struct Employee {
char *firstname;
char *lastname;
char *title;
int  salary;
};
```

...

```
 struct Employee* stuff = malloc(NUMEMPS* sizeof *stuff);
```

only allocates enough room to store a single `struct Employee`, that is: three pointers and an integer.  There's no storage for the character strings *pointed to*.

Instead, consider `malloc()`ing each of the constituent character data and assigning to `stuff->firstname` (et al), or modify the declaration of `struct Employee` to include character arrays.

Comment: -1 because the malloc does not include the room for a struct Employee, but rather for 10 pointers to struct Employee

Comment: @user3629249, you did not read the answer carefully.  No code is proposed in this answer, only cited from the question.  "This code: `...cited code...` only allocates"